# jQuery.initialize with webpack2

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

i'm moving my project to webpack2 and have a problem with jQuery.initialize

```
require('jquery');
require('jquery.initialize/jquery.initialize.min.js');

$(document).ready(function () {
  // ========================================
  // comment editor.
  // ========================================
  $('.comment-editor textarea[name=content]').initialize(function () {
    $(this).froalaEditor({
```

so this froalaEditor call is not happening. any ideas?

also tried this

```
  $.initialize('.comment-editor textarea[name=content]', function() {
    console.log('test');
  });
```

getting;

```
comment.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: $.initialize is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (comment.js:13)
    at mightThrow (jquery.js:3583)
    at process (jquery.js:3651)
```

my webpack config;

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    frontend: './assets/js/frontend/frontend.js',
    backend: './assets/js/backend/backend.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] },
      //{ test: /\.css$/, use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader' }) },
      { test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png|eot|svg|woff|woff2|ttf)$/, use: 'file-loader' }, // font & image loader
      { test: require.resolve('jquery'), use: [{ loader: 'expose-loader', options: '$' }] }, // globally expose $ for jQuery.
      //{ test: /\.js$/, exclude: [/node_modules/], use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader', options: { presets: ['es2015'] } }] }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      'node_modules',
      'assets/vendor/components'
    ],
    //alias: { jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery.js' }
  },
  plugins: [
    // new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/\.\/locale$/), // Fixes warning in moment-with-locales.min.js; Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './locale' in ...
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jquery: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' })
  ],
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do **import** not **require**

import `jquery` from 'jquery'

as jquery npm package .